# why yield return new waitforseconds not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Follows are my code:

```
void Start ()
{
    Debug.Log("before");
    StartCoroutine(CharTooLong());
    Debug.Log("after");
}
IEnumerator CharTooLong(){
    Debug.Log ("up");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    Debug.Log ("down");
}
```

I just use both method to run,but the console just print follows:

```
before
up
after
```

Why is "down" not printed? I have import DoTween in my unity, it is effects?

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It should work that way. Are you sure that the game object is still alive after the 2 seconds have passed?

Comment: Try `yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);`

Answer (score 3):

`WaitForSeconds` will not work if game is paused (`timescale = 0`) Restarting game will not reset timescale. You can check your current timescale in `Edit -> Project settings -> Time` check Time Scale parameter.

Either make sure you have proper timescale or use alternative to `WaitForSeconds`:

```c#
void Start ()
{
    Debug.Log("before");
    StartCoroutine(CharTooLong());
    Debug.Log("after");
}
IEnumerator CharTooLong(){
    Debug.Log ("up");
    yield return new WaitForUnscaledSeconds(2);
    Debug.Log ("down");
}

public static IEnumerator WaitForUnscaledSeconds(float time){
    float ttl = 0;
    while(time > ttl){
        ttl += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,it is run success. i just use time.timeScale = 0, so that ienumerator can not run normally。

Comment: Helped a lot, I was losing my mind on this...project settings had time scale = 0, I assume default time would be 1?

Answer (score 0):

You used `unityScript` tag but your code is c#! if you are using `UnityScript` , your code must be like this:

```
function Start () {
    Debug.Log("before");
    StartCoroutine("CharTooLong");
    Debug.Log("after");
}

function movement() {
    Debug.Log ("up");
    yield WaitForSeconds(2);
    Debug.Log ("down");
}
```